# Deploying Django Channels with nginx

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, nginx, websocket

I am trying to deploy the Django application in AWS ubuntu os with Django channels, Using Nginx.
I had configured the Django server in Nginx.
But I don't know how to configure channels or Redis-server in Nginx.

##### My nginx config is as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 52.77.215.218;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/
    }
}
```

##### My settings.py:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("127.0.0.1", 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

##### My requirements.txt:

```
aioredis==1.3.1
asgiref==3.5.2
async-timeout==4.0.2
attrs==22.1.0
autobahn==22.7.1
Automat==20.2.0
certifi==2022.6.15
cffi==1.15.1
channels==3.0.5
channels-redis==2.4.2
charset-normalizer==2.1.1
constantly==15.1.0
coreapi==2.3.3
coreschema==0.0.4
cryptography==37.0.4
daphne==3.0.2
defusedxml==0.7.1
Django==4.1
django-cors-headers==3.13.0
django-templated-mail==1.1.1
djangorestframework==3.13.1
djangorestframework-simplejwt==4.8.0
djoser==2.1.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
hiredis==2.0.0
hyperlink==21.0.0
idna==3.3
incremental==21.3.0
itypes==1.2.0
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
msgpack==0.6.2
mysql==0.0.3
mysqlclient==2.1.1
oauthlib==3.2.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycparser==2.21
PyJWT==2.4.0
pyOpenSSL==22.0.0
python3-openid==3.2.0
pytz==2022.2.1
requests==2.28.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
service-identity==21.1.0
six==1.16.0
social-auth-app-django==4.0.0
social-auth-core==4.3.0
sqlparse==0.4.2
Twisted==22.4.0
twisted-iocpsupport==1.0.2
txaio==22.2.1
typing_extensions==4.3.0
tzdata==2022.2
uritemplate==4.1.1
urllib3==1.26.12
zope.interface==5.4.0
```

When I run server with `python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`
Server running good and also connecting with redis-server but when
I run server with `gunicorn app.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:800` then failed to
connect with webbsocket.

I also tried Hostinger VPS as well, but Same Issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to download Daphne.

Daphne is a high-performance websocket server for Django channels.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/asgi/daphne/

https://github.com/django/daphne

https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deploying.html

How you can run daphne:
`daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8070 django_project.asgi:application`

Here is my Nginx conf for channels:

```
upstream django {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}
upstream websockets{
    server 127.0.0.1:8070;
}

server {
    ...
    ...
   

    location /ws {
        proxy_pass http://websockets;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        ...
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django; 
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please write little bit about how this is working. I can see the daphne is running on 8070 and shall serve the websocket request. What is this django 8080 about. Does it mean that the http is going to another server e.g. gunicorn and ws to daphne? How do we spin both if our backend is simple run using daphne. Thank you

Comment: Yes, 8080 would then be running gunicorn, as per recommendation in the channels documentation to be conservative about stability. You might also feel inclined to use a WSGI server because daphne does not support workers. When using code from stackoverflow, please try to gather an understanding of what it is doing beforehand. If you feel you do not need a feature, you are your own person to make your own decisions. @SardarFaisal https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deploying.html#http-and-websocket